# Marginal likelihood of bivariate Gaussian model

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, marginal-distribution, integral, wishart-distribution

I assume the following model for a sample $y_1 \in \mathbb{R}^2$ of size $1$ with bivariate Gaussian likelihood and independent bivariate Gaussian and inverse-Wishart prior for the mean and variance parameters, respectively. That is

$$ y_1 \mid \mu, \Sigma \sim \mbox{Normal}(y_1 \mid\texttt{mean}=\mu, \texttt{Var}=\Sigma) \\
\mu \sim \mbox{Normal}(\mu \mid\texttt{mean}=\mu_\mu, \texttt{Var}=\Sigma_\mu)\\
\Sigma \sim \mbox{Inverse-Wishart}(\Sigma\mid\texttt{df}=\nu_\Sigma,\texttt{scale}=S_\Sigma)
$$

I want to derive the analytical expression of the marginal likelihood of $y_1$, that is
$$
p(y_1)=\iint p(y_1 \mid \mu, \Sigma) \, p(\mu) \, p(\Sigma) \mathrm{d}\mu \mathrm{d}\Sigma,
$$
where, with an abuse of notation, $p(x)$ denotes the density of $x$ evaluated in the point $x$.

**Remark:** I know that if I assume a conjugate Normal-Inverse-Wishart prior such result is well-known and coincide with a Generalized-T distribution evaluated in $y_1$. See for instance [Wikipedia Conjugate Prior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior). However, I do not want to change my prior.

**My attempt:** Relying on well-known conjugacy results (see [Wikipedia Conjugate Prior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior)) I know how to solve one of the two integral fixing either $\mu$ or $\Sigma$, but I cannot solve (that is find a tractable analytical expression in terms of well-known functions) the second integral.